# Hide item from List

Tags: android

I would like to hide specific items from list (which contain some word). How can i do it? I am trying something like this but this hide all list.

```
     for (FruitsModel fruitsModel: fruitsList){
                    if(FruitsModel.getStatus().equals("Banana")){
                        FruitsModel.recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }else
                        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                recyclerView.setAdapter(fruitsAdapter);
```

Comment: It is hiding all the list because you are setting your recyclerview visiblity to gone

Comment: Yeah, so  how can i hide specific item which contains this word?

Comment: you can removed models from list instead of hide view

Comment: Remove those items from fruitsList  instead of setting the reciclerView visibility to gone?

Comment: I can't remove this item, because I am must use all list items to to future filtering.

Comment: @Firmer send us your view holder code.

Answer (score 2):

You have to either remove the item from that list and notify the adapter with the updated list.
Or If you wanna have the whole list, then add a visibility boolean field in the `FruitModel` and change the status of the item you want to hide.
And in `onBindViewHolder` function set the visibility based on the visibility boolean.

Answer (score 1):

You should ideally have an array of all words which you want to hide the view for

```
List<String> x = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Banana", "Aple"));
List<String> y = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then in your code you can check if the list of values is present to hide

```
      for (FruitsModel fruitsModel: fruitsList){
            if(!x.contains(FruitsModel.getStatus())){
                y.add(fruitsModel)
            }
        }
fruitsAdapter.list = fruitsModel
recyclerView.setAdapter(fruitsAdapter);
```

Comment: May i know the reason for down voting? who ever has done it?

Comment: You are setting the reciclerView visibility to gone - it won't display anything. 
You need to change the datasource or to filter those items in the adapterView perhaps.

Comment: @CuriousMind i have edited my answer, This should work fine now

Answer (score 1):

I would personally prefer do it in a different way, instead of hide an element, you could change the array adapter from which the list is created.

If your purpouse is to create filters or something like that look at this sample.

```
val originalList= mutableListOf("Banana", "Apple, "Apple", "Ananas")
```

**remove all banana**

```
val filteredList = originalList.removeAll(listOf("Banana");
recyclerView.setAdapter(filteredList);
```

The filter variable Banana could be your selected element that you wanan hide and if you do like this you will not loose the original list

Answer (score 1):

Filter your list before to setAdapter, is an easier way to do this, of course, you can do another way as filter patter explained in this link bellow
https://www.androidhive.info/2017/11/android-recyclerview-with-search-filter-functionality/

```
List<String> x = new ArrayList<String>();
for (FruitsModel fruitsModel: fruitsList){
    if(!FruitsModel.getStatus().equals("Banana")){
        x.add(fruitsModel)
    }
}
fruitsAdapter.list = fruitsModel
recyclerView.setAdapter(fruitsAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

in onBindViewHolder method of your recyclerviewAdapter put below code and you are good to go

```
@Override  
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {  
    FruitsModel fruitsModel = yourdataList[position];  

      if(!fruitsModel.getStatus().equals("Banana")){
         //your code to set 
         }

}
```